# creating a user by using useradd

Tags: linux

am using

```
useradd -u 1005 -G 1006 -c hi -d /home/redhat /s /bin/bash redhat
```

but it's showing wrong

Comment: It is - s, not /s

Answer (score 1):

You need `-s` to specify the shell, not `/s`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```
useradd -u 1005 -G 1006 -c hi -d /home/redhat -s /bin/bash redhat
```

Comment: am applied this command also but it's showing like                                          [root@localhost ~]# useradd -u 1005 -G 1006 -c hi -d /home/red -s /bin/bash red
useradd: group '1006' does not exist (error)
[root@localhost ~]#

Answer (score -4):

Check this to add a new user called ‘test’, use the following command.

```
$ useradd test
```

When we add a new user in Linux with ‘useradd’ command it gets created in a locked state and to unlock that user account, we need to set a password for that account with the ‘passwd’ command.

```
$ passwd test
Changing password for user tecmint.
New UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
```